# Meaning of 2D and 3D block of threads in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Can someone clearly in simple words explain 2D block and 3D thread blocks?
1D block is just a group of threads right.
So, what is 2D block of threads?

Answer (score 4):

All threads in CUDA have three dimensional indices. The built-in variable `threadIdx` has three members, `threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y and threadIdx.z`.

A 2D block of threads is simply a group of threads with a two dimensional indexing scheme. Similarly, a 3D block of threads is a group of threads with a three dimensional indexing scheme.

Viewed another way, a 1D block of threads is a particular case of 3D block of threads where two of the dimensions are equal to one, and a 2D block of threads is a particular case where one of the dimensions is equal to one.

All this is clearly discussed in the [first section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) of the CUDA programming guide, if you care to read it.